# What is meant by experiencing god?

Tags: krishna, philosophy, vedanta

Let us take an example of a person suffering from famine, what he needs is food what he will ask for is food, experiencing god will not come to his mind first, so what does god want us to experience?Some people are becoming monks etc are they are right or wrong,why doesnt god correct the wrong ones?Some people dont even try for god at old age whats for them?

Comment: Qn is too broad and scattered.Not readable.Ask your doubts point wise along with answers you read abt them on this forum+your analysis regarding the same+your doubts regarding the same.